# Is there any info on cavern elf names?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, elf

Are the cavern elves using normal elven names or did they take on the names of the other races from their new home like they took on the samurai profession? Is there any info on this?

Answer (score 3):

It is currently unclear if Cavern Elves differ significantly from other Elves.

In the 2nd Edition Playtest, the Cavern Elf Ancestry was called [Jinin](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Jinin) tying them to clan of elves that *had* spent centuries in caverns before migrating to central Tian Xia. They are a splinter group of the same refugees that would become the Drow of Golarion.

They removed this implication from the formal printing; however, I would think you could take inspiration from Tian names as well as Elven when making a Cavern Elf. I would hypothesize that they wanted players to be able to be from a *different* cavern if Tian culture doesn't fit your concept (and possibly including making "drow" PC's available until they can be written in formally).